# REST: different routes vs filters in controller

Tags: php, rest, laravel-4

I have events, subdivided in One-day events, Recurrent events and Festivals.

Should I create a different routes for each type of event, or should I handle the different event types on a single route `api_v1/events`, and send a parameter `eventType` from the client and make the filter based on this parameter?

I have an abstract class for the event, from which I will extend the different event types, so my plan would be to instantiate a different class in the resource controller based on this parameter.
The only problem is that I will have a lot of code repetition, ie.

```
if(eventtype == 'festival'){}
```

etc...  for index, show, etc methods.
That seems bad practise to me.
What would design wise be the best option to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't see why you'll have a lot of code repetition of stuff like `if(eventtype == 'festival'){} `.... the whole purpose of inheritance is that you code should for the most part not care what type of event this is. Can you give examples of this repetition?

Comment: For example, if I call the 'show' method on a festival, I need data returned for this event type, and that content will vary for each event type, although the basic properties are the same (the abstract class).  Therefore, for each event type, I thought to instantiate a different subclass from the "event" base class.

Comment: Isn't that just 1 thing: altering a template based on type? What are the others? What are all the others? And mind you: you can provide abstract methods that will handle the nitty gritty things in-class instead of outside of it.

Comment: Yes, but as I do this for the show method, I would need to do the same thing for the index and update method in the resource controller. The way I see it currently: Router -> Resource Controller -> instantiate specific class -> do stuff such as db interaction -> get & return result;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a route for each.

```
/api/events/recurring // returns all recurring events
/api/events/one-day // all one day events
/api/events/festivals // all festivals
```

Then for individual events

```
/api/events/recurring/{eventName} // returns a specific event
// etc...
```

So, the basic structure is

```
/api/events/{eventType}/{eventName}
```

In your code you would want two handlers:

```
/api/events/{eventType} // handles multiple events
/api/events/{eventType}/{eventName} // handles a single event
```

Comment: Just watched an interesting presentation about REST. Indeed, convention would be to use: /{type}/{id}/{sub-type}/{id}

Comment: Being truly restful would mean that you have sort of a sitemap of your API which would contain the links to the events part, and (if decided so) to the URLs of distinct types of events. If every event basically is the same, why would you deviate from the usual `/api/events/{id}`. If you know which event you want to get or change, anything more than an ID is more data than needed to identify the event. The interesting part is searching for events. Limiting the search to certain types should be a parameter to the search function.

Comment: Yes, the search will be either based on name - or category/subcategory (not the same as event type) and Google maps bounds. What makes this complex is the information that the resource will represent. The "general event data" behind the event type will be common for any of these types (which is why I need api/event), but if I would call the "show" method for a resource and add a certain search parameter (like when only showing information that is specific to a certain event type), the methods implementation called will be different for each event type.